# Como crear un VirtualHost de Apache que el programa esta escuchando por el puerto 8000?

Tags: linux, apache, centos7

Necesito crear un virtualhost para icecast que usa el puerto 8000, ya tengo su subdominio pero ahora el virtualhost creo que debe configurarse de manera distinta ya que no sirve con escribir solamente el subdominio en ServerName, no encuentro la forma de hacer que apunte al puerto 8000 de la ip del VPS

Comment: Utiliza Webmin, eso te hace automáticamente toda las configuraciones requeridas.

Answer (score 1):

Hola buenas supongo que ya lo habrás probado, pero por si acaso prueba con esta config en el virtualhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin admin@email.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        ServerName dominio.com
        ServerAlias www.dominio.com

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Recuerda cambiar la configuración del dominio y la ruta.